# NOT Exists with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, exists

`Class_List` table

| Class_List_id | Class_id |
| --- | --- |
| 341 | 4 |
| 342 | 4 |

`Lesson_CLass` table

| Class_List_id | Lesson_id |
| --- | --- |
| 341 | 22 |
| 342 | 22 |

I am trying to work out a NOT EXIST IN query, which finds all the Class_List_ids in the Class_List table that do not exist in the Lesson_CLass table where the Lesson_id is 21 and class ID is 4.

```
 SELECT Class_List.class_id, Class_List.Class_List_id 
 FROM Class_List WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
 Class_List.class_id, Class_List.Class_List_id, 
 Lesson_CLass.Class_List_id, Lesson_CLass.Lesson_id 
 FROM Class_List, Lesson_CLass where 
 (Class_List.Class_List_id=Lesson_CLass.Class_List_id) AND 
 (Lesson_CLass.Lesson_id=21) AND (Class_List.Class_id=4));
```

This results in all the Class_List records rather than the ones that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` for this purpose

```
 SELECT cl.class_id, cl.Class_List_id 
 FROM Class_List cl
 left join Lesson_CLass lc 
 on cl.Class_List_id = lc.Class_List_id
 and (lc.Lesson_id = 21 and cl.Class_id = 4)
 where lc.Class_List_ids is null;
```

Comment: It still gives the same result as the original query even after a left join